# Why if I'm checking if a line exists in a text file it's not acting when the line exists?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
if (@"d:\Keywords.txt".Contains(line))
{
}
else
{
    w.WriteLine(line);
}
```

I see in notepad that in Keywords.txt there is the line:

> Daniel

And line is now Daniel
But it still doing the w.WriteLine(line);

Why is that ?

Comment: In no place are you checking the contents of a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"d:\Keywords.txt"` is a string, so you are checking if `line` is contained within `"d:\Keywords.txt"` string (it is not, that why it goes to `else`). If you want to load contents of files then you can use (e.g.) `File.ReadAllLines`:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("d:\Keywords.txt"); 
if(lines.Contains(line))  
{
    // do something 
}
```

Full list of `File` class methods are available [@MSDN File Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't this check if any of whole line is equal to daniel? I would personally check if the first string in the array contains "Daniel" then the second etc. as apose to if a whole line in the file is equal to "Daniel"

Comment: Yes, my code will return true only if there is line with `Daniel` string (exact match, so `Hi Daniel` won't be found). It wasn't specified in question, but since this is accepted answer I assume it is correct.

Comment: In case someone was looking how to check if any line contains string (within) then take a look at @LukeHennerley answer

Answer (score 1):

Because string "d:\Keywords.txt" doesn't contain Daniel line

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not loading the file, you're checking the string `d:\Keywords.txt` for `Daniel`

To load the file and check the contents, try

```
string fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\Keywords.txt");
if(fileContents.Contains(line))
{
    //Desired code here
}
else
{
    w.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\Keywords.txt").Any(x => x.Contains(line));
```

Will get what you want or to match a string exactly

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\Keywords.txt").Any(x => x.Equals(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking to see if the string `d:\Keywords.txt` contains the value `Daniel`.  You are **not** opening the file and looking at it's contents.  It does not so you are getting to the else statement.

Take a look at MSDN's documentation on how to [Read Text from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Contains call here is checking if the actual string @"d:\Keywords.txt" contains your search string, not the contents of keywords.txt.

Try something like:

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\Keywords.txt"))
        {
            if (sr.ReadToEnd().ToString().Contains(line) == false)
            {
                w.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first read the lines from file

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\Keywords.txt");

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
               // check for your "line" here
    }
```

Comment: This is also correct, you could alternatively do this in one line using LINQ.